# Use list comprehension to build a function

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I wrote a function with Haskell to extract some values from this data type :

```
data Result = ResuVal Double     
              | ResuValIdx Double (Maybe Int)   
              | ResuValCpt Double Int           
              | NoResu                  
              deriving (Show)
```

This function extract the `Int` values in the `Result` data type and concatenate them in a list.

```
catIdxCpt :: [Result] -> [Int]
catIdxCpt [] = []
catIdxCpt (x:xs) = case x of
                ResuValIdx v (Just i) -> i:catIdxCpt xs
                ResuValCpt v c -> c:catIdxCpt xs      
                _ -> catIdxCpt xs
```

This function is working well but I first tried to wrote it with a comprehension list such as :

```
catIdxCpt ls = [i | ResuValIdx v (Just i)  <- ls  ]
```

or

```
catIdxCpt ls = [i | ResuValIdx v (Just i)  <- ls | ResuValCpt v i  <- ls ]
```

and other combinations. But I didn't managed to have the expected result.

**Do you know how to built (if it is possible) the `catIdxCpt` function with a list comprehension ?**

Comment: Interesting side note: The last version of the comprehension (`[i | ... | ... ]`) can actually be used to `zipWithN` several lists via the `ParallelListComprehension` extension. Doesn't help here, but it has its uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[x | l <- ls, x <- [i | ResuValIdx v (Just i) <- [l]] ++ [i | ResuValCpt v i <- [l]]]
```

Alternatively, consider:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

catIdxCpt :: [Result] -> [Int]
catIdxCpt = mapMaybe $ \case
  ResuValIdx v (Just i) -> Just i
  ResuValCpt v c -> Just c
  _ -> Nothing
```

Comment: The first answer manages to make the code half as efficient and a third as readable for the sake of ... ummm...

Answer (score 4):

Your function involves both mapping and filtering, so consider this technique:

```
foo xs = [ y | Just y <- map go xs ]
  where go (ResuValIdx _ (Just i)) = Just i
        go (ResuValCpt v c)        = Just c
        go _                       = Nothing
```

The helper function `go` returns `Nothing` for elements you want to remove.

The pattern `Just y <- zs` will select only those elements from the list `zs` which match the pattern `Just y`.